# Will thepresence of clicking the message box affect program output sequence

Tags: c#

I am trying to write C# code for a memory game. I would like to present the matrix( with 3 elements) to the viewer first, then a number of options for each element, highlighting that cell at a time. User has to select the correct element from  the answer panel. The display answer matrix (defined as a task) does this. The output sequence (display matrix, display answer etc. for each element shown at first) works fine if I put a message box in the for loop of display answer task. I click after every answer show and wait for next. It works fine. But if i remove the message box ( so no click required), program stops after answer showing(for the first element).could anyone help me?
relevant code portions are:

```
Mainform{
......declare number of textboxes and lables...for matrix display
}
 In the Buttonclick from the main form:
{
var firstTask = new Task(() => invokedisplaymatrix(MatrixInfoValues));

var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith((t) => invokedisplayblankmatrix(MatrixInfoValues));

var thirdTask = secondTask.ContinueWith((t) =>invokedisplayanswermatrix(MatrixInfoValues));

var fourthTask = thirdTask.ContinueWith((t) => invokedDoselection(MatrixInfoValues));

            firstTask.Start();
}
  private void invokedisplaymatrix(object Minfo1)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                Invoke(new displaymatrixdelegate(displaymatrix), new object[] { Minfo1 });
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }

        }

        private void invokedisplayblankmatrix(object Minfo2)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                Invoke(new displayblankmatrixdelegate(displayblankmatrix), new object[] { Minfo2 });
            }

        }

        private void invokedisplayanswermatrix(object Minfo3)
        {

            lock (this)
            {
                Invoke(new displayanswermatrixdelegate(displayanswermatrix), new object[] { Minfo3 });
                // Invoke(new displaymatrixdelegate(displaymatrix),new object[] {indx});
            }
        }
..Then in the display answer matrix function:

 public void displayanswermatrix(int[] Minfo3)

        {
 foreach (int ind in FilledTextBoxID2)

            {
                foreach (Control c in splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is TextBox && c != null)
                    {
                        if ((boxindexL + 1) == FilledTextBoxID2[j])
                        {
                            c.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            c.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                        }
                       boxindexL = boxindexL + 1;
                    }

                }

                int AnswerLocation = RandomNumber(1, 5);
                int[] answeroptions=excludenumberfromarray(MatrixValues2[j]); //write a function to make random numbers between 1 and 9 excluding MatrixValues2[j]

                foreach (Control c in splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is TextBox)
                    {

                        //c.Text = Convert.ToString(boxindexR);
                            //answeroptions[boxindexR]);
                        if ((boxindexR + 1) == AnswerLocation)
                        {
                            c.Text = Convert.ToString(MatrixValues2[j]); //boxindexR = boxindexR - 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            c.Text = Convert.ToString(answeroptions[boxindexR]);
                        }
                       //
                       //}//placing the required number in the randomly selected box
                       boxindexR = boxindexR + 1;
                    }
                 }


                Thread.Sleep(2000);
               MessageBox.Show("hello after one number");
 j = j + 1;
                boxindexR = 0; boxindexL = 0;
            }//end of first foreach

        }//display answer matrix end
```

If I comment the message box, the interface sleeps there after the first element display.
May I know how this error comes?

Comment: can you post some code please? would be helpful

Comment: we need to see relevant code here (**not everything**); what you describe sounds like simply a bug in your code; we can't debug it without seeing it

Comment: that code is virtually impenetrable, however: yes if you are using threads, adding extra delays could well impact things. It is really not obvious what you are trying to do here, or why you are using threading like that, or why you are locking to call the UI thread.

Comment: I have a little knowledge in C# and i did all these by searching in this website and google, whenever  I got some errors. I actually wish to build up a matrix game which is controlled by brain signals. For that I need to build the game first. I created a windows form and made 2 panels. First panel displays 3 elements. I have to show the matrix to the user for 2 sec. That is why i sleep the thread. Then each cell of the matrix is highlighted and answers are displayed on right panel. I don't know how to wait in program other than threading. Could you advise me?

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping on the UI thread is **never** a good idea - that just marks the program as unresponsive. The UI cannot make itself available to service things like paint-requests until your method finishes - but your method (by sleeping for 2 seconds over and over) *is not allowing that*. I suspect the `MessageBox` usage is forcing a redraw outside of the code message-loop, so : working, but working for the wrong reasons.

Basically, if you have delays and pauses, you shouldn't be handling that with `Sleep` - you should be using some form of `Timer`. This will allow you to *get a callback* in 2 seconds, rather than sleep for 2 seconds, but (importantly) lets the app actually respond to the message queue in the interim - i.e. lets it draw itself.

However! If you simply switch to a `Timer`, you can't do those things as continuations, as the initial "start doing stuff" call will only last a few milliseconds while it sets up the first image.

Conclusion: you've out-clevered yourself using lots of fancy `Task` etc, when all you need is a `Timer`, and a callback (`Tick` / `Elapsed`) that says:

```
- is there any more of X to do? 
  - yes: do (a single) X
  - no: is there any more of Y to do? 
    - yes: do (a single) Y
    - no: is there any more of Z to do?
      - yes: do (a single) Z
      - no: stop timer
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Marc. I tried to study timer class. May I know how to set the time for timer? is it timer.interval? Also can you give a small idea on how to do call back?

Comment: @Kavitha depends on which framework you are using. In the case of a winforms Timer, you just handle the `Tick` event and set `Interval` - it will automatically raise on the UI thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961341/timer-continuously-firing-in-c-not-able-to-stop, Could you please help me in this timer issue? thanks a lot.