# Timer continuously firing in C#, Not able to stop

Tags: c#, .net, timer

Could any one help me to stop my timer in windows form C3 application? I added timer in form using designer and interval is set as 1000; I would like to do some actions after 5 seconds of waiting after button click. Please check the code and advise me. Problem now is I get MessageBox2 infinitely and never gets the timer stop.

```
static int count;

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        }
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        timer1.Enabled = true;

        while(count>5)
         {
          ....dosome actions...
         }

        }
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count1++;
           MessageBox.Show("Messagebox2");
           if (count1 == 5)
           {
               //timer1.Enabled = false; timer1.Stop(); 
               ((System.Timers.Timer)sender).Enabled = false;
               MessageBox.Show("stopping timer");
           }
        }
```

Comment: where is count1? Who does count1 belong to? it is also a static? do you set it to 0 somewhere?

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code.  But start by losing the message box, use Debug.Print instead.

Comment: Convert the 'sender' to System.Windows.Forms.Timer first of all.

Comment: Tip: print out the value `count1` and see if that matches your expectations.

Comment: Your `button1_Click` method checks `count` immediately after starting the timer.  If `count` has been initialized to something less than 5 the `while` loop won't execute and the method will end.  This smells like something that calls for a timer and a background worker thread.

Answer (score 2):

I would render the `count` useless and just use the `timer 1 interval` property and put your actions in the `timer1_Tick` event.

```
  public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          timer1.Interval = 5000;
          timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        timer1.Enabled = false;  
        MessageBox.Show("stopping timer");
        // Your other actions here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `count1` and checking `count`.

```
while(count1 > 5)
{
    ...dosome actions...
}
```

Comment: _"I added timer in form using designer and interval is set as 1000"_

Answer (score 0):

Which Timer do you use? Because C# supports class Timer from two different namespaces. One is from Forms, the other is from System.Timers. I would suggest you to use the other one - System.Timers.Timer.

```
                Timer t = new Timer(20000); // created with 20seconds
            t.Enabled = true; // enables firing Elapsed event
            t.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
                \\do stuff
            };

            t.Start();
```

In this short code you can see how the timer is created and enabled. By registering to the Elapsed event you explicitly say what to do after the time elapses. and this is done just once.  Of course, there are some changes needed in case user clicks button before your limit is reached. But this is highly dependent on behavior  of the action you demand.

Comment: I took timer from toolbox to put in the form

Comment: And this is precisely the one from System.Windows.Forms namespace. The one from System.Timers, will do the same and I think it is better for use.